# program path is missing or invalid

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

I've got the following problem. I'm trying to debug my program. The main file is obviously `main.c`.
When I compile, I run the command `gcc -g -o main *.c ./rcv/*.c -lm -lpthread`.
`main.c` is in the `src` directory, while other `.c` files are in the `./rcv` directory. Here is my `launch.json`

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "C:\\Users\\r.dipascale\\Desktop\\vscode\\RTKLIB\\src\\main",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Abilita la riformattazione per gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Imposta Versione Disassembly su Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In VS Code, when I open `main.c` and click on `Execute -> Start Debug`, I can see the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hhT1.png)

Answer (score 0):

##### It says that the file is not in executable format because the file name must end with ".exe"

The file name is "main" and it needs to be for e.g "main.exe"

This needs to be your compiling Command Line:

```
gcc -g -o main.exe *.c ./rcv/*.c -lm -lpthread
```

Comment: thank you for your help, but unfortunately the error remains...

Comment: Did you also change the "program" line in launch.json?

Comment: @domandestack — did you update the JSON to specify 'main.exe' instead of just 'main'?

Comment: "program": "C:\\Users\\r.dipascale\\Desktop\\vscode\\RTKLIB\\src\\main.exe",

Comment: Are you compiling in linux?

Comment: there are no compilation error, and the main.exe is in that folder. I'm compiling on wsl, but my os is windows 10

Comment: that's the reason. Gcc is generating an elf "that targets SYSTEM V(linux...)" compatible executable image. You need a compatible "PE" windows image. To get that, download the gcc crosscompiler "GCC for windows". I consider using "MINGW-GCC". Personally, i was somewhat lazy that i downloaded it by downloading codeblocks, because the downloading process is a bit complicated. Here is the link to codeblocks, it will include gcc and other gnu-tools as well. https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/20.03/Windows/codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe/download

Comment: To easily use gcc by command line. Type edit environment variables in windows search bar then click "environnement variables...", goto path and add "C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin"

Comment: Hello, is that working ??